# Latest News module not going away?

Tags: joomla-3.x, module

So I tried to remove the latest news module. But it just kept on displaying on my home-page. How can i make it go away? I tried to clear cache, that did not work, also if I change the Menu Item Type of the home-page from featured articles to something else, the latest news module disappears then. How can I make it disappear without changing the Menu Item Type?

I tried to unpublished it but it wont go away, also there is no code for the module in the index.php.

I just noticed that my css does not load properly. It will probably look something like this, everything in the red box needs to be removed.

[image]

Comment: Share link and I will guide you through.

Comment: Am i right in assuming you have disabled it? And also disabled the correct module?

Comment: Yes, i'm 100% sure I did that

Comment: @SalilMomin http://nerdyfuture.byethost24.com/. link to my website the pictures next to the top news should be removed

Comment: Ok what I would recommend you do as I assume this is a development site, is firstly disable **ALL** modules in the Module Manager. Once done, report back with the results

Comment: The part you want to remove is from your featured/blog menu item, please see my answer for updated solution.

Answer (score 1):

You might be disabling the wrong module, or maybe there's a copy somewhere with a different name.

The best way to find and disable the correct module is to login to your site on the front-end. Go to http://nerdyfuture.byethost24.com/?option=com_users&view=login and login with your superadmin user. Then return to your homepage, and when hovering over your modules you should see an icon similar to this:

[image: Module edit icon]

Hover over the icon to see some details about the module (Name and position), and click it to edit it in the back-end. Now you can disable it, and once you click <kbd>Save & Close</kbd> it should be gone.

**Update**
It's possible that the news section is from a module called Mini-frontpage (from what I see in your source code). Make sure you've located and disabled all instances of this module. You can filter the module list by *module type* in the Joomla module manager like this:

[image]

**Update 2**
Those elements you want to remove are not modules, they are your featured/blog articles loaded in the component area. Basically you have to find a way to hide the component (loaded with `<jdoc:include type="component" />` in your template). Some templates has a setting for this, if not you have to create an `if-else` statement using PHP to determine if the component should be loaded or not. Here's an article on how to detect if the user is viewing the frontpage.

You can try to **replace** `<jdoc:include type="component" />` with the following code in your `index.php` file:

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() != $menu->getDefault()) {
    echo '<jdoc:include type="component" />';
}
?>
```

This should load the main component area on all pages *except* your homepage.

Comment: Thanks, Alright I tried that, the problem is that there is no editing icon for the module itself, there are icons for the articles. So if i try to edit something, it will edit the article not the module.

Comment: @NerdZilla I have updated my answer with another option, but after looking closer at your website I'm a little confused as to what part you want to remove...

Comment: @Lodder Well, it did not go away, but I found something very strange, what i did is just unpublished every module I had. After that my web-page was completely empty, it also removed the latest news. But if I add a module, for example the carousel, the latest news comes back in the left upper corner.(The module is not made by the Mini Frontpage, it is just a standard joomla latest article module)

Comment: I tried to put the code you gave my on a lot of different places. But it is still showing. Could this maybe be a wrong option in the configuration ? Thank you very much for all the effort!

Comment: Yes, I will send you an a email

Comment: I send you a e-mail